# How to override spring-boot application properties in spring-boot 1.4.3

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-boot, integration-testing

In our project we setup our integration tests by overriding the properties in the `IntegrationTest` annotation as shown below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJunitClassRunner.class)
@IntegrationTest("server.port:0",
                  "health.hystrix.enabled:false"
                   .... other properties ....
                )
@ActiveProfile("local","no-swagger")
public class IntegrationTest{
}
```

However in spring-boot 1.4 `@IntegrationTest` annotation has been deprecated. Spring documentation suggests using `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead.
My question is How do I override the properties with this new annotation?

Answer (score 3):

What I understand [from the docs](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) is that you are able to override properties inside `@SpringBootTest`.

> The `@SpringBootTest` annotation also has a properties attribute that
>   can be used to specify any additional properties that should be
>   defined in the Environment. Properties are now loaded in the exact
>   same way as Spring’s regular `@TestPropertySource` annotation.

[And also the javadoc of `@SpringBootTest` says](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html):

> `@AliasFor(value="value")`
>
> `public abstract String[] properties`
>
> **Properties** in form `key=value` that should be added to the Spring
>   Environment before the test runs.
>
> **Returns:** the properties to add

So simply override the properties inside `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties={"server.port=0"})
```

Comment: +1 but [SpringBootTes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html)t's javadoc is worth linking too.